# coffee script not working

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I'm doing rails application and i'm going to deep down in Javascript for my behaviour of my web application so this is the problem

i have Newsfeed with many post and post have many comment the comment was hide with in the post

post.css

```
#comments-section{
  display: none;
}
```

post/index "News feed"

```
<%= link_to "Comments", "#", id: "comments-link" %>

<section id="comments-section">

  <%= render 'commenters/newsfeedcomment', obj: post %>

  <% if current_user == post.user %>
    <h6 align="right"><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %></h6>
    <h6 align="right"><%= link_to 'Delete', { :id => post ,:controller => 'posts',:action => 'destroy'} %></h6>
  <% end %>
</section>
```

now i'm try to check my comment link to trigger but its not working and i dont know how to debbug

```
$(document).on "page:change", ->
  $('#comments-link').click ->
    alert "clicked"
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, if you are going to have multiple of `#comments-link` then you should make it a class instead of an id.

Secondly, is your problem that you are using Turbolinks? There's a `jquery.turbolinks` gem that makes Turbolinks `page:change` events work like DOM ready events.

Thirdly, you could also put the listener on some DOM element that doesn't enter and leave and DOM.

```
$('.container').on 'click', '#comments-link' ->
  alert 'clicked'
```

This attaches one listener to the `.container` element but only listens for events that come from the `#comments-link` element(s).

Comment: thanks for the reply but i dont really understand i guess i need to study the basic of the Javascript again thanks for the reply im really appreciate